# PyQT: How to set Combobox Read-Only

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox

I know there is .setEnabled(bool) method available for Combobox widget. But aside from making it unavailable this method grays this widget out. What I need is to set Combobox so it appears an active but yet remains read only. Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas? Don't do it. Don't let GUI elements look like something that they aren't. This is neither intuitive for the user, nor advisable for the developper.

Comment: as other comment mentioned you shouldn't do this since it's not intended by the system, means that user will not expect your program to behave like this which would cause complications and is bad practice. If you could elaborate what your program is exactly we could offer some other solutions. 

Best you could do is remove items and leave only user's item if you want 1 selection, I don't think it's possible to disable it without greying it out.

Comment: if you really need to, you could change it's appearance using `setStyleSheet("color: ...")`

Comment: There are two listWidgets displaying the same Class of items with the exactly same attributes. First ListWidget is read-only. When the user clicks an item the combobox only "delivers" an information. Combobox still properly displays the right attribute name from all available options but changing it to somethingelse won't change ListWidget Item's attribute. Another listWidget dispays the items in read-and-write mode. Meaning changing an attribute using combobox pull-down menu will change item's attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to clobber the appropriate event handlers. This could be done with either a subclass:

```
class ComboBox(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QComboBox.__init__(self, parent)
        self.readonly = False

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if not self.readonly:
            QtGui.QComboBox.mousePressEvent(self, event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if not self.readonly:
            QtGui.QComboBox.keyPressEvent(self, event)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if not self.readonly():
            QtGui.QComboBox.wheelEvent(self, event)
```

or with an event-filter:

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)  
        self.combo = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.combo.readonly = False
        self.combo.installEventFilter(self)
        ...

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (source is self.combo and self.combo.readonly and (
            event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress or
            event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress or
            event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Wheel)):
            return True
        return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, source, event)
```

Personally, though, I would prefer to either disable the combo box, or perhaps reset its list of items so there was only one choice.

Answer (score 2):

Its a little late but if someone need a ComboBox which is readonly after setting a text to it you can use the setEnabled() method which disable any Qwidget.

so

```
self.cb = QComboBox()
self.cb.setEditText("Whatever")
self.cb.setEnabled(False)
```

I hope i could help

Comment: thanks for introducing me to QWidget.setEnambled ... does the job nicely :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
cb=QComboBox()
cb.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)
```

or

```
LE=QLineEdit()
LE.setReadOnly(True)
self.comboBox.setLineEdit(LE)
```

QComboBox has a method **lineEdit**. just pass it so it can access QLineEdit methods

i hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

your answer is you need to set the setEditable as False.

```
self.comboBox.setEditable(False)
```

and, you can also achieve this by not setting the Editable Flag in the Model

```
def flags( self,index):
    return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled |QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
```

---

This is unrelated but you seem to ask a lot of questions that can be solved just by looking at the PyQt Class Reference, We are happy to help you but asking questions that can be solved easily doesn't make sense and is a waste of your valuable time .

Here is the link to the reference . [Reference Link](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html)

Comment: `setEditable` only changes wheather the text content of the combo box can be edited, combo boxes are already not editable by default, so `setEditable(False)` won't really have any effect here.

Comment: @mata : true, just laying down all the options.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs! But apparently a question I've asked goes beyond of doc's combobox class description. Since there is no method available to get what I need (from a combobox).